# Android Release Version and "Waiting for Debugger"

Tags: android, release

I know this has been asked before but I still don't have a solution.
My first app: developed and debugged on my moto droid and then followed all the release steps, (exported from Eclipse, using my key to sign) including removing the debug in the manifest xml.

I copied the resulting apk to the droid, disconnected the usb and installed it by double clicking on the file using Astro.

I get the "Waiting for Debugger" message like when I am debugging but it never goes away.

Doing something real stupid I know but I can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 69):

Yes, restart your phone. It worked for me.

Comment: Anyone has any idea why this happens? On my phone other apps (I was developing) worked just fine. Debugger or no debugger. Only one of them insisted on waiting for the debugger no matter what. Up until I restarted the device ofc...

Answer (score 12):

I just restart my phone and the problem is solved ：）

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at this? http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/bdf61367c8649f4a

Or http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/4a46c34d799f95dd

It sounds like the phone's global debug flag is on and you can change that with the DevTool

Comment: Thanks. I saw those but they didn't click for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

For those getting this annoying behavior in 4.2.2 you have to un-check the setting for "wait for debugger" in the developer options. Of course, those options were hidden by Google, and you have to do a sneaky trick to get them to show back up. I had set them before they disappeared, and couldn't for the life of me find them again.

[This page explains the procedure](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/11/13/reminder-tip-developer-options-are-hidden-in-android-4-2-heres-how-to-find-them/)

Answer (score 2):

Restarting works in most cases. and it worked for this case. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Just deactivate the USB debugger functionality on your device when you want to test your installed APK.
I just did it and it works.

Answer (score -3):

Great, Development.apk is the solution.
Download it from http://bozosort.com/content/2009/10/android-devtools-app/

OK. I think that it works because that Development.apk resetting debug flag of my gphone,
or may also because i restart my phone after i install Development.apk.

Comment: I just downloaded this software. It looks nice, but I still don't know how that gets ride off the mentioned roblem (which I also have).